# How to determine a failed kubernetes deployment?

Tags: kubernetes

I create a Pod with Replica count of say 2, which runs an application ( a simple web-server), basically it's always running command - However due to mis-configuration, sometimes the command exits and the pod is then Terminated.

Due to default `restartPolicy` of `Always` the pod (and hence the container) is restarted and eventually the Pod status is `CrashLoopBackOff`.

If I do a `kubectl describe deployment`, it shows Condition as `Progressing=True` and `Available=False`.

This looks fine - the question is - how do I mark my deployment as 'failed' in the above case?

Adding a `spec.ProgressDeadlineSeconds` doesn't seem to be having an effect.

Will simply saying `restartPolicy` as `Never` be enough in the Pod specification?

A related question, is there a way of getting this information as a trigger/webhook, without doing a `rollout status` watch?

Comment: What do you mean by 'mark deployment as failed'?

Comment: I have an orchestration logic - that's outside - which needs to know the deployment status - and when it is Failed - we can rollback it.

Comment: So why do you not like `rollout status` then? Given a readinessProbe it should either return OK on good deployment or a bad on failed, tie in your failing logic there

Comment: Ok, so you suggest readiness probe - but if readinessprobe fails - that means the application will be restarted by `kubelet` (after reading the documentation). `rollout status` is like polling - I'd prefer something that calls a webhook or any mechanism - where application 'tells' I am not starting and ideally great if is handled by the orchestration logic and not 'extra code per container'. Simply setting `restartPolicy` to `never` will work? What if the node goes down - will the pod be restarted on another. Documentation says so - but is not explicit.

Comment: There are no webhooks in the API that I'm aware of. All clients poll. Look at readinessProbe, you can tweak how long it'll try things for and fail in the end. And even then there's no failed mark per se it just means that after x time there's still no good pod. I would recommend against setting restartPolicy to never for any kind of deployment (or stateful or daemon set). It could be useful for a cron job or a bare pod if you have logic creating those.

Comment: Thanks. That's why the question about should `restartPolicy` be used. I guess that's not advisable. I also wanted to check if I was missing something because it looks unlikely that `k8s` wont provide something like this.

Answer (score 4):

### A bit of theory

Regarding your question:

> How do I mark my deployment as 'failed' in the above case?

Kubernetes gives you [two types](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-setting-up-health-checks-with-readiness-and-liveness-probes) of health checks:

**1 ) Readiness**
Readiness probes are designed to let Kubernetes know when your app is **ready to serve traffic**. 
Kubernetes makes sure the readiness probe passes before allowing a service to send traffic to the pod. 
If a readiness probe starts to fail, Kubernetes stops sending traffic to the pod until it passes.

**2 ) Liveness**
Liveness probes let Kubernetes know if your app is **alive or dead**. 
If you app is alive, then Kubernetes leaves it alone. If your app is dead, Kubernetes removes the Pod and starts a new one to replace it.

At the moment (v1.19.0) , Kubernetes has support for 3 types mechanisms for implementing liveness and readiness probes:

**A ) ExecAction**: Executes a specified command inside the container. The diagnostic is considered successful if the command exits with a status code of 0.

**B ) TCPSocketAction**: Performs a TCP check against the Pod's IP address on a specified port. The diagnostic is considered successful if the port is open.

**C ) HTTPGetAction**: Performs an HTTP GET request against the Pod's IP address on a specified port and path. The diagnostic is considered successful if the response has a status code greater than or equal to 200 and less than 400.

---

### In your case:

If the process in your container is able to crash on its own whenever it encounters an issue or becomes unhealthy, **you do not necessarily need a liveness probe**; the kubelet will automatically perform the correct action in accordance with the Pod's restartPolicy.

I think that in your case (the need to refer to a deployment as succeed / failed and take the proper action) **you should**:

**Step 1:** 
Setup a HTTP/TCP  **readiness Probe** - for example:

```
   readinessProbe:
      httpGet:
         path: /health-check
         port: 8080
      initialDelaySeconds: 5
      periodSeconds: 5
      failureThreshold: 2
```

Where:

`initialDelaySeconds` — The number of seconds since the container has started before the readiness probe can be initiated.

`periodSeconds` — How often to perform the readiness probe.

`failureThreshold` — The number of tries to perform the readiness probe if the probe fails on pod start.

**Step 2:**
Choose the relevant [rolling update strategy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#strategy) and how you should handle cases of failures of new pods (consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52121422/how-to-automatically-stop-rolling-update-when-crashloopbackoff/64451702#64451702) thread for examples).

A few references you can follow:

[Container probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-probes)
[Kubernetes Liveness and Readiness Probes](https://blog.colinbreck.com/kubernetes-liveness-and-readiness-probes-how-to-avoid-shooting-yourself-in-the-foot/#:%7E:text=Kubernetes%20uses%20liveness%20probes%20to%20know%20when%20to%20restart%20a%20container.&text=Kubernetes%20uses%20readiness%20probes%20to,the%20backends%20for%20a%20service.)
[Kubernetes : Configure Liveness and Readiness Probes](https://alibaba-cloud.medium.com/kubernetes-configure-liveness-and-readiness-probes-588aa2cab90d)
[Kubernetes and Containers Best Practices - Health Probes](https://www.magalix.com/blog/kubernetes-and-containers-best-practices-health-probes)
[Creating Liveness Probes for your Node.js application in Kubernetes](https://medium.com/kubernetes-tutorials/creating-liveness-probes-for-your-node-js-application-in-kubernetes-285fd6d22497)

---

#### A Failed Deployment

A deployment (or the rollout process) will be considered as **Failed**
if it tries to deploy its newest ReplicaSet without ever completing over and over again until the `progressDeadlineSeconds` interval has exceeded.

Then K8S you update the status with:

```
Conditions:
  Type            Status  Reason
  ----            ------  ------
  Available       True    MinimumReplicasAvailable
  Progressing     False   ProgressDeadlineExceeded
  ReplicaFailure  True    FailedCreate
```

Read more in [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#failed-deployment).

Answer (score 1):

There is no Kubernetes concept for a "failed" deployment. Editing a deployment registers your intent that the new ReplicaSet is to be created, and k8s will repeatedly try to make that intent happen. Any errors that are hit along the way will cause the rollout to block, but they will not cause k8s to abort the deployment.

AFAIK, the best you can do (as of 1.9) is to apply a deadline to the Deployment, which will add a Condition that you can detect when a deployment gets stuck; see https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#failed-deployment and https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#progress-deadline-seconds.

It's possible to overlay your own definitions of failure on top of the statuses that k8s provides, but this is quite difficult to do in a generic way; see this issue for a (long!) discussion on the current status of this: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/1899

Here's some Python code (using `pykube`) that I wrote a while ago that implements my own definition of ready; I abort my deploy script if this condition does not obtain after 5 minutes.

```
def _is_deployment_ready(d, deployment):
    if not deployment.ready:
        _log.debug('Deployment not completed.')
        return False

    if deployment.obj["status"]["replicas"] > deployment.replicas:
        _log.debug('Old replicas not terminated.')
        return False

    selector = deployment.obj['spec']['selector']['matchLabels']
    pods = Pod.objects(d.api).filter(namespace=d.namespace, selector=selector)
    if not pods:
        _log.info('No pods found.')
        return False

    for pod in pods:
        _log.info('Is pod %s ready? %s.', pod.name, pod.ready)
        if not pod.ready:
            _log.debug('Pod status: %s', pod.obj['status'])
            return False
    _log.info('All pods ready.')
    return True
```

Note the individual pod check, which is required because a deployment seems to be deemed 'ready' when the rollout completes (i.e. all pods are created), not when all of the pods are ready.

Comment: So essentially it means one has to keep polling for 'pod readiness' (for some definition of readiness). BTW, max-deadline-seconds didn't work for me as I mentioned in the original question. I will wait for some more time if someone comes up with an answer that does not involve polling (but looks like that's what one has to do), for now I'd definitely upvote this.

Comment: If it's the polling that you are trying to avoid, you could try to hook into the k8s events API; the apiserver emits events when objects transition state, so for example the `for pod in pods` polling loop above could be made more efficient by waiting for a Pod lifecycle event (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/). You could also wait for the `Deployment available` event.

E.g. see https://github.com/softonic/kubewatch for a way to do this on the command line.