# How to automatically stop rolling update when CrashLoopBackOff?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I use Google Kubernetes Engine and I intentionally put an error in the code. I was hoping the rolling update will stop when it discovers the status is `CrashLoopBackOff`, but it wasn't.

In this [page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/), they say..

> The Deployment controller will stop the bad rollout automatically, and
>   will stop scaling up the new ReplicaSet. This depends on the
>   rollingUpdate parameters (maxUnavailable specifically) that you have
>   specified.

But it's not happening, is it only if the status `ImagePullBackOff`?

Below is my configuration.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: volume-service
  labels:
    group: volume
    tier: service
spec:
  replicas: 4
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 2
      maxSurge: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        group: volume
        tier: service
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: volume-service
        image: gcr.io/example/volume-service:latest
```

P.S. I already read liveness/readiness probes, but I don't think it can stop a rolling update? or is it?

Comment: If you're using liveness/readiness probes, that also can stop the rolling update. I recommend playing with this feature a bit to understand how maxSurge and maxUnavailable work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I just need to set `minReadySeconds` and it stops the rolling update when the new replicaSet has status `CrashLoopBackOff` or something like `Exited with status code 1`. So now the old replicaSet still available and not updated.

Here is the new config.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: volume-service
  labels:
    group: volume
    tier: service
spec:
  replicas: 4
  minReadySeconds: 60
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 2
      maxSurge: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        group: volume
        tier: service
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: volume-service
        image: gcr.io/example/volume-service:latest
```

Thank you for averyone help!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @*Nicola_Ben* - I would also consider changing to the setup below:

```
spec:
  replicas: 4
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 1 <----- I want at least (4)-[1] = 3 available pods.
      maxSurge: 1       <----- I want maximum  (4)+[1] = 5 total running pods.
```

Or even change `maxSurge` to `0`.
This will help us to expose less possibly nonfunctional pods (like we would do in [canary release](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CanaryRelease.html#:%7E:text=Canary%20release%20is%20a%20technique,making%20it%20available%20to%20everybody.)).

Like @*Hana_Alaydrus* suggested its important to setup `minReadySeconds`.

With addition to that, sometimes we need to take more actions after the rollout execution. 
(For example, there are cases when the new pods not functioning properly but the process running inside the container haven't crash).

A suggestion for a general debug process:

1 ) First of all, pause the rollout with:
`kubectl rollout pause deployment <name>`.

2 ) Debug the relevant pods and decide how to continue (maybe we can continue with with the new release, maybe not).

3 ) We would have to resume the rollout with: `kubectl rollout resume deployment <name>`  because even if we decided to return to previous release with the `undo` command (4.B) we need first to `resume` the rollout.

4.A ) Continue with new release.

4.B ) Return to previous release with:  `kubectl rollout undo deployment <name>`.

---

Below is a visual summary (click inside in order to view the comments):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The explanation you quoted is correct, and it means that the new replicaSet (the one with the error) will not proceed to completion, but it will be stopped in its progression to the `maxSurge`+`maxUnavailable` count. And the old replicaSet will be present too.

Here the example I tried with:

```
spec:
  replicas: 4
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 1
      maxSurge: 1
```

And these are the results:

```
NAME                                  READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
pod/volume-service-6bb8dd677f-2xpwn   0/1       ImagePullBackOff   0          42s
pod/volume-service-6bb8dd677f-gcwj6   0/1       ImagePullBackOff   0          42s
pod/volume-service-c98fd8d-kfff2      1/1       Running            0          59s
pod/volume-service-c98fd8d-wcjkz      1/1       Running            0          28m
pod/volume-service-c98fd8d-xvhbm      1/1       Running            0          28m

NAME                                              DESIRED   CURRENT   READY     AGE
replicaset.extensions/volume-service-6bb8dd677f   2         2         0         26m
replicaset.extensions/volume-service-c98fd8d      3         3         3         28m
```

My new replicaSet will start only 2 new pods (1 slot from the `maxUnavailable` and 1 slot from the `maxSurge`).

The old replicaSet will keep running 3 pods (4 - 1 `unAvailable`).

The two params you set in the `rollingUpdate` section are the key point, but you can play also with other factors like `readinessProbe`, `livenessProbe`, `minReadySeconds`, `progressDeadlineSeconds`.

For them, [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#rolling-update-deployment) the reference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I already understand this. But Im looking to stop the rolling update when the status `CrashLoopBackOff` or something like `Exited with status code 1`

Comment: I find this unfortunate too, since there could be a probability that your container might restart like 5 times in which the first restart contains error logs that might not be the same as the following ones caused by issue after initial issue. So getting --previous log is useless.